# Delimiter gives excess space when omitting integers

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner, delimiter

This is code that reads a file "input.txt" and only takes capital and lowercase letters. It omits all numbers using a delimiter. The "input.txt" file has the following info:

```
tree
Harry167
FEE00LING 
blo73b
worry
45hapPY2
```

I want the output to be

```
tree
Harry
FEELING 
blob
worry
hapPY
```

But I am getting

```
tree

Harry




FEE

LING 

blo

b

worry



hapPY
```

```
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class HuffTree
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);

        sc.useDelimiter("[^A-Za-z]");
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        System.out.println(sc.next());
    }
}
```

Comment: To format code, input, and outputs prefix those lines with four spaces or select them and press ctrl+k. You can use the toolbar button `{}` too. For more information see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with your regex. Currently, your `Scanner` is using each individual number (not letter) as the delimiter, then the blank lines aren't coming from your Scanner but from the `System.out.println`, as `sc.next()` is returning blank tokens.

To fix this issue, simply add a + to the end of your regex to make it look like this:
`[^A-Za-z]+`

This groups common matching characters into a single match to be used as the delimiter.

Read more about the plus quantifier here:
https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html